# importing reducer/action in jest throwing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

My jest tests work fine with components. However on importing an **action** it throws the following error with errors pointing to react-dom **mount** methods.

```
Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

ReactDom is being called in some other tests, but even after removing it, error persists.

On importing **reducer** following is thrown

```
 Expected the reducer to be a function.
```

> Meanwhile, minimal code to recreate this looks like

```
import { someAction } from './actions';
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281607/react-jest-testing-nested-component-connected-to-redux-gives-invariant-violat?rq=1)

Basically you need

```
jest.mock("./index.js", () => "root");
```

Im not entirely sure why test suite would fail because we're not using DOM while testing actions/reducers.